# Twine hangs without prompting for password

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I'm attempting to upload a tarball and wheel for a new package to PyPI using `twine` which was recently installed under a conda environment (Miniconda3). After I enter my username I expect to be prompted for my password, but this never happens and everything just hangs.

```
$ twine --version
twine version 1.11.0 (pkginfo: 1.4.2, requests: 2.19.1, setuptools: 40.2.0,
requests-toolbelt: 0.8.0, tqdm: 4.25.0)

$ twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
Uploading distributions to https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
Enter your username: my_user_name
```

What might be causing this unexpected behavior?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, please file an issue: https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/new

Comment: Thanks, @Dustin. https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/390

Comment: BTW this appears to not be isolated to twine, as I have just experienced a similar issue when using the Anaconda client which hung after username (no password prompt) but it worked in the Windows DOS console. This appears to be (more likely) an issue with the git bash shell console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to move past this issue by using the DOS console (i.e. `cmd.exe`) for this instead.

If anyone can comment as to why this authentication step doesn't work as expected in the git/bash console for Windows then please chime in, as I'd like to fix that (hopefully a config setting?) so I don't have to move over to DOS for this step in my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still having this issue in 2023 with Git bash. A workaround I've found without swapping console is to provide the password as an argument. E.g.

```
python -m twine upload -p "<your_password>" dist/*
```

Obviously not ideal but it does work (still asks for your username).